# Calculating large data in Node on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a service that I run daily in the background with a database of about 140mb in size. The calculations I run require me to load all 140mb into Node at once, and after a minute or so quickly reach the process limit of 512mb and Heroku restarts the process.

For the mean time, a quick solution is to increase the server to 2X so I get 1 GB RAM, but within a month or so the database will outgrow that as well.

As far as Heroku goes, is my option basically to upgrade Dyno options? Since these are calculations I do once per day, I would rather run them locally on my machine and upload the results than to pay $250-500/month for the Performance Dynos.

I know I could also just upgrade to the Performance Dynos to run these services and then downgrade once finished, but I'm looking for something I can automate and not have to deal with each day.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It sounds like it might be worth investing some time into inventing a way to do your calculations without all that data being in memory.  This may involve breaking the calculation into discrete steps that each operate on part of the data or may involve using some data only from the database (without loading all of it into memory) or make involve redesigning the calculation into separate pieces.  We could help you come up with ideas on this, but would need to understand a lot more about what kind of calculation you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#dyno-hour-costs) seems to fit your use case exactly. You can schedule your task to run daily on a [One-Off Dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) of any size, and since Heroku pricing is "prorated to the second" you will only pay for the time that your task is running on that Dyno.

I haven't actually used this, but I was about to recommend a similar solution on AWS when I searched and found this feature of Heroku.

Comment: I do like the fact that it automatically starts a temporary one-off dyno, but decided to use Kue instead because they don't recommend it for tasks that take more than a few minutes